# How to get the following equation in the form $A \cos(ωt+φ)$

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, wave-equation

$$v = [1+Γ] \cos(ωt)\cos(ωx/c) - [1-Γ] \sin(ωt)\sin(ωx/c) = A(x)\cos\left(ωt+\varphi\right)$$

I need to express the above function as a product of two functions, f(x) and f(t) where one is dependent on distance, the other dependent on time.

The final form will therefore be: $A\sin(ωt + φ)$ or $A\cos(ωt + φ)$ either is fine.

Where $A$ is the function dependent on distance, $x$.

I need to do this so I can isolate the ‘A’ function that will in essence describe the amplitude function of the above wave-equation with transmission line distance.

I’m sure this is an easy problem but I have been really struggleing with doing this. It must be possible.

I would greatly apprciante your help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

We can use the [linear combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Linear_combinations) formula for sine and cosine, that is

$$a\cos x+b\sin x=c\cos(x+\varphi)$$

with

- $c = \operatorname{sign(a)} \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$
- $\varphi = \operatorname{arctan} \left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)$

that is

$$v = [1+Γ] \cos(ωt)\cos(ωx/c) - [1-Γ] \sin(ωt)\sin(ωx/c) = A(x)\cos\left(ωt+\varphi\right)$$

with

- $A(x) = \operatorname{sign\left([1+Γ] \cos(ωx/c)\right)} \sqrt{([1+Γ] \cos(ωx/c))^2+ ([1-Γ] \sin(ωx/c))^2}=$

$$= \operatorname{sign\left([1+Γ] \cos(ωx/c)\right)}\sqrt{1+Γ^2+2Γ\cos(2ωx/c)}$$

- $\varphi = \operatorname{arctan} \left(-\frac{[1-Γ] \sin(ωx/c)}{[1+Γ] \cos(ωx/c)}\right)$

Comment: I thought $\phi$ had to be independent of $x$.

Comment: Oh yes! It’s a bad typo! thanks

Comment: Firstly thank you so much for answer this. Unfortunately, I do not understand your answer. What is 'sign'? And second, the final answer written in EEE handbooks is: $A = \sqrt{ (1 + \Gamma)^2 + 4 \Gamma \cos^2{\left(\omega x/c\right)}  }$ I would greatly appreciate showing me how to go to that from the original wave-expression. Thank you!

Comment: @AdrianSalt sign(a) is the [sign function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function), we can simply assume a positive sign if the quantity $[1+Γ] \cos(ωx/c)>0$.

Comment: Recall that $\cos 2\theta=\cos^2\theta - \sin^2 \theta=2\cos^2 \theta-1$ therefore $2Γ\cos(2ωx/c)=4Γ\cos^2(ωx/c)-2Γ$ which leads to $A(x)=\sqrt{(1-Γ)^2+4Γ\cos^2(ωx/c)}$.